# Random IE10 seam displays when doing a translation with a border-radius

Tags: html, css, animation

I am looking for a little advice for what seems to be a rendering bug in IE10.  I created a animated-flip and it work in all the browsers I care about.  While in testing I find random borders-like lines getting displayed for no reason.  They are not actual border, outlines nor shadows being applied from what I can tell.  It seems like the child elements (such as the anchor in the example) are simply not being rendered correctly.

I know a similar effect can happen on mobile-safari and people use `margin-whatever: -1` but that does not seem to have an effect here.

I cut down the example to the bare minimum needed to reproduce the bug.  It seems if I remove any of these styles the problem goes away.

```
perspective: 2000px;              // Remove and the animation looks awful
border-radius: 6px;               // Remove and the modal will look different then all others
-ms-transform: rotateY(0); 
transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
```

[DEMO](http://codepen.io/scispear/pen/ahizu?editors=110)

Comment: I don't see the issue, can you add a picture? I only notice theedges are not as smooth but not the lines you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

My example may help you

```
body {
  background: #555;  
}
.pt, .front {
  width: 100px;
}
.pt {
  margin: 0 auto;

}
.front {
  position: absolute;
  background: #FFF;
  padding: 20px;
  transform: scale(0.8) scaleZ(1.0) rotateX(9deg) rotateY(9deg);
  transform-origin: 0% 0%;
  perspective: 200;
  perspective-origin: 50% 50%;
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.8) scaleZ(1.0) rotateX(9deg) rotateY(9deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0% 0%;
  -webkit-perspective: 200;
  -webkit-perspective-origin: 50% 50%;
  -moz-transform: scale(0.8) scaleZ(1.0) rotateX(9deg) rotateY(9deg);
  -moz-transform-origin: 0% 0%;
  -moz-perspective: 200;
  -moz-perspective-origin: 50% 50%;
  -o-transform: scale(0.8) scaleZ(1.0) rotateX(9deg) rotateY(9deg);
  -o-transform-origin: 0% 0%;
  -o-perspective: 200;
  -o-perspective-origin: 50% 50%;
  -ms-transform: scale(0.8) scaleZ(1.0) rotateX(9deg) rotateY(9deg);
  -ms-transform-origin: 0% 0%;
  -ms-perspective: 200;
  -ms-perspective-origin: 50% 50%;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  border-radius: 6px 6px 6px 6px;
  -moz-border-radius: 6px 6px 6px 6px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 6px 6px 6px 6px;
}
```

Comment: Please consider including some information about your answer, rather than simply posting code. We try to provide not just 'fixes', but help people learn. You should explain what was wrong in the original code, what you did differently, and why your change(s) worked.